# Getting and saving data to Postgres JSON field

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg

I have the following table in PostgresSQL DB:

```
CREATE TABLE unit(
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   unit_capabilities JSON,
);
```

I have following insert query:

```
INSERT INTO unit (unit_capabilities)
VALUES ('[{"type": "din", "on": 1, "off": 2}, {"type": "dou", "on": 3, "off": 4}]');
```

I am using NodeJS with the "pg" package to query that data, but they return in the following format:

```
[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;din&quot;,&quot;on&quot;:1,&quot;off&quot;:2},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;dou&quot;,&quot;on&quot;:3,&quot;off&quot;:4}]
```

I can not parse this into a JSON object. I am getting the following error:

```
error: invalid input syntax for type json
```

How would I make this work? What is the best way to use my setup (NodeJS and PG package) to store and retrieve data from the PostgreSQL JSON field?

Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: Column names in your `insert` don't match the ones in you table definition, `id` vs `unit_id`. The data types in your `insert` don't match your table columns either, you're trying to put a `text` or `uuid` into a `serial` column. `pg` package should [handle parsing json](https://node-postgres.com/features/types#:~:text=type%20parsing%20examples,for%20the%20server.) on its way to the database and back for you

Comment: @Zegarek sorry that was my typo when I tried to simplify the example. I have fixed this. I am retrieving those data and consol logging them and that is what I am getting.

Comment: You're getting HTML entities, which don't have anything to do with JSON. There must be something else going on.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thanks, you are right, something else is going on. I am using an express validator that escapes all HTML entities. Such a silly error got me especially I am not doing this the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I am so sorry to everyone involved. I realized this is due to the fact I am using an express validator with the following setup:

```
  check('unit_capabilities').trim().escape().exists()
```

As per above, this escapes all the HTML entities, thanks to @Álvaro González for pointing that out.